# rails resque worker memory consumption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, memory-consumption

I am using a resque gem to process my background process.

I have setup three queue with one worker each.

Can any one explain how the memory gets consumed with increase and decrease of worker in the queue.

I have heard that each worker loads up separate Rails environment. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, each worker start a separate Rails environment, so if you have three workers you will have three Rails environments loaded. 
Having more workers won't make your queue to grow longer, it will be the number of jobs queued what will make it to grow.

Either way, if you don't have any major reason to have 3 separate workers I suggest you to have only one worker for all queues and separate them as your application scales with time.

Comment: Resque does not load the rails environment, as a matter of fact not loading rails and low memory consumption are exactly the main project's goals. see here: https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque

Comment: @HenryMazza yes it DOES load the Rails environment. Run a Resque process, then change your application code (update a worker), trigger the worker and watch Resque run the old code. That's why when you deploy changes you have to restart your Resque processes.

Answer (score -3):

It's not true. As I explained in my comment here, the precise goal of Resque is not to load a rails environment for each worker (see https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque).

Due to a limitation caused by ruby's green trheading solution, you should launch at least one worker per processor core to be able to use the the whole CPU. This is why the default behavior of Resque is to launch each worker in a separate process. It means launch N parallel processes at the same time, each with the full gem set loaded independently. This is the main cause of high memory use for Resque and to any other Ruby tool. You can see [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/09/16/improving-resques-memory-efficiency/) how things can get better using native threading with the JVM.

So if you want keep your Resque memory usage down keep your workers dependencies as low as you can. And always is very important to use a monitoring tool like God or Bluepill to keep an eye in the process.

Comment: I think you are confusing workers with jobs. Of course Resque doesn't load the environment for each job, but it does for each worker. What resque does when a new job is queued is forking the worker process so it doesn't have to load the environment again and asuring the main worker process doesn't hang if the job fails.

Comment: To clarify this, take a look at the readme file of Resque:        By default Resque won't know about your application's environment. That is, it won't be able to find and run your jobs - it needs to load your application into memory.

If we've installed Resque as a Rails plugin, we might run this command from our RAILS_ROOT:

$ QUEUE=file_serve rake environment resque:work

Comment: "By default Resque won't know about your application's environment." - It won't load unless you tell it to. If yo you are concerned with memory consumption you shouldn't use "environment". For instance, if you will run 4 workers with "environment" it will load rails 4 times in memory.

So if you make your code rails dependent it's your fault, not theirs. Even so you can optimize, like load only active record if what you want is make database jobs. On my daily use a worker never uses more than 20MB idle with all my libs loaded. Rails alone is more than 60MB.